# gofstat issue with fit list

Tags: r, statistics

I get an error when I execute gofstat() R function with a list of fitdist. I do not the meaning of this error and what is causing it.

```
> gofstat(list(fitw, fitg, fitln), fitnames=c("weibull", "gamma", "lnorm"))
Error in names(Chi2$chisqpvalue) <- names(Chi2$chisqdf) <- fitnames[1] : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

The entire code I am using is the following. I suppose it is related with prob vector, as the same script with other data-set provides the results.

```
prob <- c(0.004926108, 0.510983890, 0.306590334, 0.048409000, 0.032272667, 0.005378778, 0.005378778, 0.037651445, 0.005378778, 0.037651445, 0.005378778)

fitw <- fitdist(prob, distr = "weibull", method = "mle")
fitg<- fitdist(prob, distr = "gamma", method = "mle")
fitln <- fitdist(prob, distr = "lnorm", method = "mle")
gofstat(list(fitw, fitg, fitln), fitnames=c("weibull", "gamma", "lnorm"))
```

The werid part for me is that gofstat works individually:

```
> gofstat(fitw)
Goodness-of-fit statistics
                             1-mle-weibull
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic     0.2354052
Cramer-von Mises statistic       0.1426774
Anderson-Darling statistic       0.8750089

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                               1-mle-weibull
Akaike's Information Criterion     -33.74893
Bayesian Information Criterion     -32.95314
> gofstat(fitg)
Goodness-of-fit statistics
                             1-mle-gamma
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic   0.2760907
Cramer-von Mises statistic     0.1983721
Anderson-Darling statistic     1.1044287

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                               1-mle-gamma
Akaike's Information Criterion   -32.26493
Bayesian Information Criterion   -31.46914
> gofstat(fitln)
Goodness-of-fit statistics
                             1-mle-lnorm
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic   0.2781579
Cramer-von Mises statistic     0.1279150
Anderson-Darling statistic     0.8426833

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                               1-mle-lnorm
Akaike's Information Criterion   -36.57233
Bayesian Information Criterion   -35.77654
```

btw, which distribution do you think it fits better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes about because it has problems defining the chisq breaks, if you look at the example you provided, there's an unexpected spike at 0.005378778 which makes it quite problematic, especially when the n is small:

```
table(prob)
prob
0.004926108 0.005378778 0.032272667 0.037651445    0.048409 0.306590334 
          1           4           1           2           1           1 
 0.51098389 
          1
```

You can try something like below, but since you most likely focus on mle, it should be ok:

```
library(fitdistrplus)

fits = lapply(fitnames,function(i){
fitdist(prob, distr = i, method = "mle")
})

 gofstat(fits,chisqbreaks=c(0,0.01,0.1,0.6))

Goodness-of-fit statistics
                             1-mle-weibull 2-mle-gamma 3-mle-lnorm
Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic     0.2354052   0.2760907   0.2781579
Cramer-von Mises statistic       0.1426774   0.1983721   0.1279150
Anderson-Darling statistic       0.8750089   1.1044287   0.8426833

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                               1-mle-weibull 2-mle-gamma 3-mle-lnorm
Akaike's Information Criterion     -33.74893   -32.26493   -36.57233
Bayesian Information Criterion     -32.95314   -31.46914   -35.77654
```

Again, your observations are limited so chisq estimation is going to be tricky. Your second question about which distribution is better, very hard to tell, because n is small, 4 repeated values.